# Visual Studio Con C++ No Tiene Librerías

Tags: visual-studio

Creo un proyecto en Visual Studio utilizando el lenguaje de programación C++ intento importar la librería con `#include <windows.h>` muestra un mensaje de error que me dice que no existe una librería con el nombre indicado  y veo que faltan muchas otras librerías. ¿Que debo hacer para poder utilizas todas las librerías que deseo?

Comment: La estas añadiendo como #include "windows.h" o #include <windows.h>, la secunda es la forma correcta. Por otro lado, esas librerías  deberían estar adjuntas en la instalación siempre y cuando hayas añadido el SDK correspondiente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diría que te falta el SDK para desarrollar en C++, [aquí](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/mt683786.aspx) tienes algunas de las opciones para instalarlo